# Spring Boot 3.1 RC1 Docker Compose can not be activated for Integration Tests

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose

I've just read the Spring Boot 3.1 RC release notes, there is a new docker compose support feature, I have tried it by building a simple example myself.

```yaml
# Define the services/containers to be run
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: productsdb
      POSTGRES_USER: user
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - ./pg-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    labels:
      org.springframework.boot.service-connection: postgres
      # org.springframework.boot.ignore: true # ignore container
```

In the *application.properties*, I set up it will be active in profiles: `default` and `it`.

```
spring.docker.compose.profiles.active=default,it
```

When running the main application class from IDEA directly, the `default` profile is picked in the console log, finally it works well, but it can not be activated in a test with profile `it`.

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("it")
class IntegrationTests { ...}
```

It is not active when running this test, I am not sure this is designed as purpose or something I misunderstood docker compose support in spring boot.
Github repos: https://github.com/hantsy/spring6-sandbox/tree/master/boot-docker-compose